# move by scrolling 3 elements with 1 event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, scroll

I'm trying to move the 3 scrollbar from 3 `<div class="container">` by the class name with the same event at one time. This is my approach:
In first place I share the event handler from the script

```
function handleScroll(event: any) {
  let position: number = event._vts
  let scrollOptions = {
    left: position,
    top: 0,
    behavior: undefined
  }

  if (event._vts) {
    if (graficas.length !== 0) {
      console.log('muevo el array')
      console.log('asi tengo el array -> ' + graficas)
      const el0 = document.getElementsByClassName('container').item(0)
      el0?.scroll(scrollOptions)
      const el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('container').item(1)
      el1?.scroll(scrollOptions)
      const el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('container').item(2)
      el2?.scroll(scrollOptions)
    } else {
      console.log('lleno el array')
      for (let index = 0; index < document.getElementsByClassName('container').length; index++) {
        graficas.push(document.getElementsByClassName('container')[index])
        document.getElementsByClassName('container')[index].scrollBy(event._vts, 0)
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('container')[index])
      }
      graficas.shift()
      console.log('asi queda el array -> ' + graficas)
    }
  }
}
```

then I share the portion of template that display the chart with the scrollbars I want to move:

```
  <h2>CPU</h2>
    <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
      <div class="containerBody">
        <Bar :data="cpu" :options="options" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>IO</h2>
    <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
      <div class="containerBody">
        <Bar :data="io" :options="options" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>SEC</h2>
    <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
      <div class="containerBody">
        <Bar :data="sec" :options="options" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea how can I approach to achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to use third-party libraries for this task? There is a Vue plugin, vue-scroll-sync, that might be able to help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll-sync Even if you can't use the library itself, maybe you can take inspiration from the implementation.

Comment: @Mayank Is there a specific reason you've added the [node.js] tag to this question? I don't see any reason to add it, since the JavaScript runs in the browser...

Comment: True, but almost always the development is done using node.js. Then it is bundled and shipped to run in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet is a modified/simplified version of the source code for [Vue Scroll Sync](https://github.com/metawin-m/vue-scroll-sync). Depending on the complexity of your needs (and your ability to use third-party dependencies in your codebase), you may want to pull that library directly, rather than hard-coding the component.

A few callouts:

- Note the use of a `uuid` to identify the different regions whose scroll position should be synced. This prevents a given scroll event being "double-counted" when the other regions' scroll positions are updated.
- In all cases, the `onScroll` handler is temporarily removed from the divs when the scroll position is being modified. Again, this prevents the "double-counting" behaviors that might impact smooth scrolling.
- The divs are styled and colored for ease of demoing, but of course, you can copy your own markup and content into the `scroll-sync` component to achieve the same effect. Deep nesting of DOM elements should still work, because the `topNode` of the component is computed on mount, and events are emitted/captured on that node.

```js
let uuid = 0;

Vue.component('scroll-sync', {
  name: 'ScrollSync',
  template: document.querySelector("#scroll-sync-template").innerHTML,
  data() {
    return {
      topNode: null
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.uuid = uuid.toString();
    uuid += 1;
  },
  mounted() {
    let parent = this.$parent
    while (parent) {
      this.topNode = parent
      parent = this.topNode.$parent
    }

    const vue = this;
    this.topNode.$on('scroll-sync', function(data) {
      if (data.emitter === vue.uuid) {
        return
      }
      const {
        scrollTop,
        scrollHeight,
        clientHeight,
        barHeight
      } = data

      const scrollTopOffset = scrollHeight - clientHeight

      vue.$el.onscroll = null
      if (scrollTopOffset > barHeight) {
        vue.$el.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        vue.$el.onscroll = vue.handleScroll
      })
    })
    this.$el.onscroll = this.handleScroll
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll: function(e) {
      const vue = this
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const {
          scrollTop,
          scrollHeight,
          clientHeight,
          offsetHeight
        } = e.target

        this.topNode.$emit('scroll-sync', {
          scrollTop,
          scrollHeight,
          clientHeight,
          barHeight: offsetHeight - clientHeight,
          emitter: vue.uuid
        })
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.scroll-sync-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <scroll-sync vertical style="height:500px;width:100px;margin-right:50px;">
      <div style="width:100px;height:1000px;background:linear-gradient(red, green, blue);"></div>
    </scroll-sync>
    <scroll-sync vertical style="height:500px;width:100px;">
      <div style="width:100px;height:2000px;background:linear-gradient(red, green, blue);"></div>
    </scroll-sync>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scroll-sync-template">
  <div class="scroll-sync-container">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1: Instead of scroll events, listen for wheel event.

Mostly users scroll by gestures or mouse wheel. With this you can easily avoid infinite loop (one scroll triggering other and vise-versa). This will not work when the user scrolls by dragging the scroll handle.

Approach 2: Listen for mouseover to know which element is directly under cursor and only use scroll event of that element to sync scrolls.